# dockercloud haproxy with more than one service on different ports

Tags: docker, spring-boot, docker-compose, haproxy

Is it possible to configure dockercloud/haproxy with more than one backend service but listening on a different port? I'm trying to get a docker-compose config working with nginx on port 80 for a web frontend, and then a container on 8080 running a Spring Boot app.

It appears by default haproxy is seeing the linked containers for web and addressbook (see .yml file below), but by default they are both being exposed on port 80 by happroxy, and so the Spring Boot container never receives traffic on 8080.

Is this config possible, or do I need to run 2 different haproxy containers too, one for web, and one for the REST backend service?

Here's my docker-compose.yml so far:

```
version: '2'

#build:
#  context: ./haproxy
#  image: haproxy
# dockerfile: Dockerfile

services:
    mongodata:
        image: mongo:3.2
    volumes:
    - /data/db
    entrypoint: /bin/bash
mongo:
    image: mongo:3.2
    depends_on: 
        - mongodata
    volumes_from:
        - mongodata
    ports:
    #only specify internal port, not external, so we can scale with docker-compose scale
        - "27017"
addressbook:
    image: addressbook
    depends_on: 
        - mongo
    environment:
        - MONGODB_DB_NAME=addressbook
    ports:
        - "8080"
    links:
        - mongo
web:
    image: docker-web-angularjs
    ports:
        - "80"
lb:
    image: dockercloud/haproxy
    #TODO: need to add an haproxy.cfg to configure for addressbook instances exposed behind 8080?
    #or can be configured via container properties?
    #image: haproxy
    depends_on: 
        - addressbook
    environment:
        - STATS_PORT=1936
        - STATS_AUTH="admin:password"
    links:
        - addressbook
        - web
    volumes:
        - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    ports:
        - 80:80
        - 8080:8080
        - 1936:1936
```

Answer (score 1):

To me, it's easier to use [Traefik](https://docs.traefik.io/) to achieve the goal.

```
addressbook:
  image: addressbook
  depends_on: 
    - mongo
  environment:
    - MONGODB_DB_NAME=addressbook
  labels:
    - "traefik.backend=spring_boot"
    - "traefik.protocol=http"
    - "traefik.port=8080"
    - "traefik.frontend.entryPoints=http_8080"
  ports:
    - "8080"
  links:
    - mongo

web:
  image: docker-web-angularjs
  labels:
    - "traefik.backend=nginx"
    - "traefik.protocol=http"
    - "traefik.port=80"
    - "traefik.frontend.entryPoints=http_80"
  ports:
    - "80"

lb:
  image: traefik
  command: "--web --web.address=8081 --docker --docker.domain=docker.localhost \
            --logLevel=DEBUG \
            --entryPoints='Name:http_80 Address::80' \
            --entryPoints='Name:http_8080 Address::8080'"
  ports:
    - 80:80
    - 8080:8080
    - 8081:8081
  volumes:
    - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    - /dev/null:/traefik.toml
```

Answer (score 0):

You can expose the two services using two different paths, both on the same port of the haproxy container. You can do this using the environment variable `VIRTUAL_HOST` for the `addressbook` and `web` containers:

```
addressbook:
    image: addressbook
    depends_on: 
        - mongo
    environment:
        - MONGODB_DB_NAME=addressbook
        - VIRTUALHOST="/addressbook/*"
    ports:
        - "8080"
    links:
        - mongo
web:
    image: docker-web-angularjs
    environment:
        - VIRTUALHOST="/web/*"
    ports:
        - "80"
```

Unfortunately, haproxy doesn't remove the `web` or `addressbook` path by default, so you need to update the two apps in order to manage a "base path".